# Multiply all values together in string format printing in java

Tags: java

I've only had a few hours practicing and learning Java so I'm still learning the basics.

I'm reading values from a text file, which contains:

Single
60 
112.50

Master
70
2227.50

Penthouse
5
5000.00

(So it appears as when run)
Room Type: Single, Bookings: 60, Room Price: £112.00, Income: £6,750.00, Tax: 1350.00 
And so fourth with each room.

I've printed all the values in a string format which is required. However, my problem is really simple.

I just want to add all the income together in a totalincome variable and add all the paidTax together in a totalpaidTax variable, then continue to print out it, to basically show the total tax paid and total income from all the rooms.
Although, I just don't know how to write it. I've had multiple attempts at trying but just no luck. 
Here's my current code.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WagesCalculator {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader("task3.txt"));
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   //Current tax variable value 
   double tax = 20;

   //User Input Y or N to change tax variable value
   System.out.println("- - Hotel Tax System - -");
   System.out.print("Do you want to specify a custom Tax Rate? [Y|N]: ");

   //if statement to change tax variable value subject to Y or N
   if (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
       System.out.print("Please enter the new tax value: ");
       tax = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
       }

   //Prints out current tax value
   System.out.println("The current tax rate is " + tax+".");

   while (file.hasNext()) {
       String name = file.next();
       int numberOfBookings = file.nextInt();
       double price = file.nextDouble();
       double income = numberOfBookings * price;
       double paidTax = income*(tax/100);
       //String format print out final calculations
       System.out.printf("Room Type: %s, Bookings: %d, Room Price:  £%.2f, Income: £%.2f, Tax: %.2f %n", name, numberOfBookings, price, income, paidTax);

       }
   file.close();
   }
```

}

Comment: And what seems to be the exact issue? If you expect help, at the very least, you have to isolate the part of your code where you're having problems.

Comment: Can you show an attempt and describe the problem?  "Add [capability] to the following code:" is not really appropriate for SO http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm just asking how you can multiple the values stored in income together, into a new variable, and add all the values from paidTax into a new variable.

I just posted the code so nobody was confused with the question.

There is no issue. I'm just asking for help with the syntax of adding all the values together. You two seem to have really blown a really simple question out the window.

Comment: well, if you want all incomes multiplied in a variable called "totalincome", then the first step would be to declare such a variable. Also, there is only one variable "income" in your code that constantly changes its value. so "multiple the values stored in income" doesn't make sense. There is only one value saved in "income" that you have to use while it's there (Inside the loop *hint* *hint*)

Comment: You wrote some code. It doesn't work. What **specific** piece of the code fails to deliver the result you expect? Is that difficult for you to comprehend? Take some time to read the Stack Overflow [help file].(http://stackoverflow.com/help) and learn how to post questions that receive answers.

Comment: Goodness me you're one unhelpful jobs worth. If I knew how to write it, I would have. I've been doing Java for a few hours and want to get ahead and simply tried seeking some advice from experts on how to do something very small. You cannot actually know something you've not been taught or told. It wasn't difficult for someone to write a few lines of code to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are your friend.

- Create an object for each Room in your input.
- Store the Rooms in a List.
- Aggregate values from the List.
- Print accordingly.

  ```
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class WagesCalculator
  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {
      WagesCalculator wc = new WagesCalculator();
      wc.calculate();
    }

    public void calculate()
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
      Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader("task3.txt"));
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Current tax variable value
      double tax = 20;

      // User Input Y or N to change tax variable value
      System.out.println("- - Hotel Tax System - -");
      System.out.print("Do you want to specify a custom Tax Rate? [Y|N]: ");

      // if statement to change tax variable value subject to Y or N
      if (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
      {
        System.out.print("Please enter the new tax value: ");
        tax = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
      }

      // Prints out current tax value
      System.out.println("The current tax rate is " + tax + ".");

      List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

      while (file.hasNext())
      {
        String name = file.next();
        int numberOfBookings = file.nextInt();
        double price = file.nextDouble();
        rooms.add(new Room(tax, name, numberOfBookings, price));
      }

      file.close();

      rooms.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
      double totalIncome = rooms.stream().map(r -> r.income)
      .reduce((a, b) -> a + b).orElse(0.0);
      double totalTax = rooms.stream().map(r -> r.tax).reduce((a, b) -> a + b)
      .orElse(0.0);
      System.out.printf("Total income was: %d\nTotal tax was %d\n", totalIncome,
      totalTax);
    }

    class Room
    {
      double tax;

      String name;

      int numberOfBookings;

      double price;

      double income;

      double paidTax;

      public Room(double tax, String name, int numberOfBookings, double price)
      {
        this.tax = tax;
        this.name = name;
        this.numberOfBookings = numberOfBookings;
        this.price = price;
        this.income = numberOfBookings * price;
        this.paidTax = income * (tax / 100);
      }

      @Override
      public String toString()
      {
        return String.format(
        "Room Type: %s, Bookings: %d, Room Price:  £%.2f, Income: £%.2f,         Tax: %.2f %n",
            name, numberOfBookings, price, income, paidTax);
      }
    }
  }
  ```